# What is the semantic meaning of mocha's (testing framework for node.js) "it" statement?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

Just started using this framework for a course and, while I've done a brief search online and of the documentation, the meaning of this keyword eludes me.

That said, I understand how to use it to define tests, but I do not understand why the heck they would use the word 'it' to denote them.

Does anyone know?

Thanks,

badPanda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it` is just a function, to provide a closure for specific tests. But, it's designed to create relatively readable statements, to further the goals of [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and [behavior-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development).

Comment: Thanks :) That is helpful. I am wondering, though, is there a meaning to the term 'it', like some sort of abbreviation?

Comment: Nope, it's not an abbreviation, it's just English for going within a describe block. it('is green'), it('returns an error with bad input'), that sort of thing.